# UIVIEW: gradiente de color como fondo completo

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, diseño

Necesito poner al `UIView` un [degradado axial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degradado) como fondo de pantalla. Aquí un ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando con una extensión de `UIVIEW`

```
func addGradient(colors: [UIColor], locations: [NSNumber]? = nil, startPoint: CGPoint, endPoint : CGPoint) {
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()        
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    gradient.name = "gradientLayer"
    gradient.colors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.1)
    gradient.locations = [1, 1]

    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
}
```

y le empleo de esta forma

```
 self.backgroundLoginView.addGradient(
           colors: [Utils.Color.CELESTE, Utils.Color.COLOR_E8E8E8],
           startPoint: CGPoint.init(x: 1, y: 1),
           endPoint: CGPoint.init(x: 1, y: 1)
 )
```

Quedando así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pruebo la respuesta utilizando

```
@IBDesignable class DesignableView: UIView {
     @IBInspectable var gradientColor1: UIColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet{
            self.setGradient()
          }
     }

     @IBInspectable var gradientColor2: UIColor = UIColor.white {
         didSet{
             self.setGradient()
           }
     }

     @IBInspectable var gradientStartPoint: CGPoint = .zero {
         didSet{
             self.setGradient()
     }
}

@IBInspectable var gradientEndPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1) {
    didSet{
        self.setGradient()
    }
}

private func setGradient()
{
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [self.gradientColor1.cgColor, self.gradientColor2.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = self.gradientStartPoint
    gradientLayer.endPoint = self.gradientEndPoint
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
    if let topLayer = self.layer.sublayers?.first, topLayer is CAGradientLayer
    {
        topLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
    self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}
```

En el `.xib` se ve bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque en el emulador se ve así :

[image]

Comment: Hay @BrunoSosaFastTag  algunas soluciones  en `stackoverflow` -de inglés- para el comportamiento expuesto en la pregunta, asimismo siento decir que por un tema de tiempo no las he podido probar en mi **iMac**. No obstante muchas de ellas coinciden en efectuar una función y/o clase de sobre escritura: `override` incluso algunas proponen no emplear los puntos `start` y  `end`, dado que el *target* es usar gradiente en toda la pantalla. En mi opinión sería analizar e intentar los códigos en el `Xcode` que se describen en:

Comment: **¿Por qué la gradiente no cubre el ancho del view?** [inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44737260/why-gradient-doesnt-cover-the-whole-width-of-the-view) y **Swift: Fondo de Gradiente para el UIView** [inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037160/swift-background-gradient-for-uiview) para ir descartando opciones y sobre todo encontrar la solución a lo expuesto en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

No es una pregunta muy clara, pero a lo que comprendo necesitas esto:

https://hackernoon.com/color-it-with-gradients-ios-a4b374c3c79f

Aunque esta en ingles tiene pasos muy fáciles de seguir.
Suerte!

Comment: Estoy siguiendo exctamente lo mismo y el resultado es un degradees que no completa la pantalla como indica de ejemplo de arriba

Comment: En el link que pasé viene un proyecto de prueba, intenta descargarlo y ver la diferencia con tu código, o subelo a un repo de Git para verlo y poder ayudarte con el

Comment: El código fuente específicamente en esta [ruta](https://github.com/pgpt10/GradientSample/tree/master/Gradient.xcodeproj/xcuserdata) contiene el  **xcuserdata**, esto crea muchos problemas mientras se realiza el `pulling` al `branch` de otros desarrolladores, por tanto es seguro ignorarlo o borrarlo, porque contiene básicamente configuraciones personales como: `breakpoint`, `layout para interface de usuario`, `archivos abiertos`, `configuración de sanpshots`, etc. *fuente: ¿Es seguro ignorar xcuserdata?* [inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462296/is-it-safe-to-ignore-xcuserdata)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con este código. saludos atte.

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
let primaryColor = UIColor(red: 210/255, green: 109/255, blue: 180/255, alpha: 1)
let secondaryColor = UIColor(red: 52/255, green: 148/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addGradient(topColor: primaryColor, bottomColor: secondaryColor)
}
```

}

extension UIView {

```
func addGradient(topColor: UIColor, bottomColor: UIColor) {
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    gradient.colors = [topColor.cgColor,bottomColor.cgColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
}
```

}